# How to align elements inside a caption using CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi I have an image review system that has a slide down caption and a slide up caption on hovering over the image. Inside the top caption I've been trying to align a review widget to the left of the caption and a few share buttons to the right of the caption. I have the elements in the caption but can't seem to get them to align.

I tried to add external css to a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/nj0mgwdr/1/
 I couldn't figure out how to get external to work so I'll paste them here:

component.css:

```
    .grid {
    padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    }

    .grid figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    }

    .grid figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    }

   .grid figcaption
   {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #49484A;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    }

    .grid share-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    .grid figcaption h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    }

    .grid figcaption span:before {
    content: 'by ';
    }

   .grid figcaption a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ed4e6e;
    color: #fff;
   }


      figcaption2
  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #49484A;
    color: #ed4e6e;
   }


     figcaption2 h3 {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     color: #fff;
   }

    figcaption2 span:before
   {
     content: 'by ';
    }

     figcaption2 a 
    {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 1px 1px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     display: inline-block;
     background: #ed4e6e;
     color: #fff;
     }

     /* Caption Style 1 */
     .cs-style-1 figure {
     overflow: hidden;
     }

      .cs-style-1 figure img {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
       transition: transform 0.4s;
     }

       .no-touch .cs-style-1 figure:hover img,
       .cs-style-1 figure.cs-hover img {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
       -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
       -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       transform: translateY(0px);
     }

      .cs-style-1 figcaption {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100%;
       top: auto;
       bottom: 0;
       opacity: 0;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
       -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
       -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
       transform: translateY(100%);
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
       transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
     }

       .no-touch .cs-style-1 figure:hover figcaption,
       .cs-style-1 figure.cs-hover figcaption {
       opacity: .95;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
       -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
       -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       transform: translateY(0px);
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
       transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
     }

       .cs-style-1 figcaption a {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 20px;
       right: 20px;
    }


   /* Caption Style 2 */
   .cs-style-2 figure {
    overflow: hidden;
   }

    .cs-style-2 figure img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
   }

    .no-touch .cs-style-2 figure:hover img,
    .cs-style-2 figure.cs-hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    }

     .cs-style-2 figcaption2 {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     bottom: auto;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
     transform: translateY(0%);
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s ease-out;
     transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s ease-out;
   }

    .no-touch .cs-style-2 figure:hover figcaption2,
    .cs-style-2 figure.cs-hover figcaption2 {
        opacity: 0.95;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
       transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
      }

     .cs-style-2 figcaption2 a {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
    }


     .share-buttons {
     width:auto;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 0;
     box-shadow: 0;
     display: inline;
   }


    .share-buttons.facebook {
    background: url('images/facebook.png') no-repeat;
    float:left;
    height: 18px;
    padding:2px;
    width: 32px;
    }
    .share-buttons.twitter {
    background: url('images/twitter.png') no-repeat;
    float: right;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 32px;

    }

    .share-buttons.pinterest {
    background: url('images/pinterest.png') no-repeat;
    float:      right;
    height:     28px;
    padding:    2px;
    width:      32px;

    }

     .share-buttons.google_plus {
    background: url('images/google_plus.png') no-repeat;
    float:      right;
    height:     28px;
    padding:    2px;
    width:      32px;

    }

    /* rating widget */
    .rate_widget{
    border:    0px solid #CCC;
    overflow:  visible;
    padding:    10px;
    position:   inherit;
    width:      180px;
    height:    15px;
    }
    .ratings_stars{
    background: url('images/star_empty.png') no-repeat;
    float:      left;
    height:     28px;
    padding:    2px;
    width:      32px;
   }
    .ratings_vote{
    background: url('images/star_full.png') no-repeat;
   }
   .ratings_over{
   background: url('images/star_highlight.png') no-repeat;
   }
   .total_votes {
    background: #A6A6A6;
    top: 28px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    position:  absolute;  
    }  
    .movie_choice{
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    width: 180px;
    }


 default.css:

   *, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
   body, html { font-size: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
    .clearfix:after { clear: both; }

    body {
        font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #b3b9bf;
        background: #f9f9f9;
     }

    a {
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:active {
    color: #333;
    }

    /* Header Style */
    .container > header {
     border:10px solid #fff;
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
    /* height:auto; */
    /*width:auto;*/


    }
    .container > header h1 {
    font-size: 2.625em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    }
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a minimally-viable example? There's way too much CSS here to wade through looking for a bug. Give the just in the Fiddle rather than the entire codebase.

Comment: @Brian Bennett Is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/95Lp0pv6/ thank you :)